Are there any features that allow for faster long rests?
Are there any features in the game that reduce the duration that long rests take? Specifically, I'm looking for:

Racial traits that set the long rest to 4 Hours or less
Any other features that further reduce the time of a long rest that stack with racial long rest reductions

I know that there is a DMG variant rule that drastically reduces the long rest time, but I'm looking for options that would help a character trying to optimize for this quality.

Out of curiosity, why optimise for this?

@SeriousBri Ideally, to take a Long Rest while your friends take a Short Rest.

Worth noting that you can only take one long rest per day

Be an Elf
Elves have the "Trance" racial trait, which means they meditate instead of sleeping, and "gain the same benefit" from four hours of meditation as "a human would from 8 hours of sleep."
Per the Sage Advice Compendium, this means that four hours of meditation count as a full long rest:

Does the Trance trait allow an elf to finish a long rest in 4 hours?
If an elf meditates during a long rest (as described in the Trance trait), the elf finishes the rest after only 4 hours. A meditating elf otherwise follows all the rules for a long rest; only the duration is changed.

See also: Is 4 hours long enough for a long rest for Elves?

I don't know of any other reliable methods for shortening a long rest, though this other post has a few far-out, might-work-sometimes suggestions: Are there any 5e spells whereby PCs can gain the benefit of a long rest without actually taking a long rest?
